# Updating a Control's property (label.Text) from another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

In my windows application I want to update a label's `Text` property from another thread when some button is clicked:

Here is the code of my button click event handler:

```
 StatusLabel.Text = "Started";
 Task.Factory
 .StartNew(() =>
    {
        … // long-running code
        StatusLabel.Text = "Done";
    }, CancellationToken.None, 
       TaskCreationOptions.None,
       TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())
 .ContinueWith(tsk =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("something broke");
        var flattened = tsk.Exception.Flatten();
        // note: Don't actually handle exceptions this way, m'kay?
        flattened.Handle(ex => { MessageBox.Show("Error:" + ex.Message); return true; });
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

When I click the button the above code is executed. I am not seeing the `StatusLabel.Text = "Started";` at once. It seems it waits for `// long-running code` and then it is executed.

What I want is to see the "Started" in the label as soon as the button is clicked, and when the long-running task is done, I want to see "Done" on the label.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two reasons why this is happening.

First, you are telling the task to run on the GUI thread, by specifying `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` as a parameter. This means that your processing is not happening on a background thread, but on a GUI thread. Second is that changing a control's property only invalidates it, meaning that it will only be redrawn once the GUI thread has done processing other jobs.

In other words, you set the value to `"Started"` (and the label only invalidates itself), and then immediately queue the "background" task to the GUI thread, keeping it busy from painting controls. Your form will appear "hanged" during this time, and you will probably be unable to even move it around.

The simplest way to do a background job in Windows Forms is to use a `BackgroundWorker`. If you, however, really want to use a `Task`, then use the simple task factory method which doesn't accept a sync context, and then make sure that all UI interactions from that background thread are invoked on a GUI thread:

```
StatusLabel.Text = "Started";

// this is the simple Task.Factory.StartNew(Action) overload
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // do some lengthy processing
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    // when done, invoke the update on a gui thread
    StatusLabel.Invoke(new Action(() => StatusLabel.Text = "Done"));
});
```

Alternatively, you may simplify the whole thing by moving GUI thread sync logic into a separate method:

```
// this method can be invoked from any thread
private void UpdateStatusLabel(string msg)
{
    if (StatusLabel.InvokeRequired)
    {
        StatusLabel.Invoke(new Action<string>(UpdateStatusLabel), msg);
        return;
    }

    StatusLabel.Text = msg;
}
```

And then simply call the method from wherever you wish:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateStatusLabel("Started");

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // do some lengthy processing
        Thread.Sleep(10000);

        // no need to invoke here
        UpdateStatusLabel("Done");
    });
}
```

Comment: +1. Suggestion: Change `this.Invoke(…)` to `label1.Invoke(…)` to make it extra-clear that we need to get on the thread where `label1` was created. (While this is probably the same thread as for `this`, it's not immediately obvious that `this` likely refers to the `Form` that contains `label1`.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, the button click happens in the UI thread, so no problem to set the label text to "Started" from there. Then you start the long running code from a different thread. Call `Invoke` method from a different thread to update UI elements after the long running code finishes:

```
Invoke((Action) (() => StatusLabel.Text = "Done"));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        // UI updates ( label text change, button enable/disable )
    });
    await task;
    await Task.Run(()=> {
      // Synchronous methods 
    });
}
```

These can be arranged any how based on requirements.
All run serially. Like here first UI update then task completes and then other synchronous methods will be run.

If those synchronous methods have UI updates again the same way has to be followed like this method. Since those updates are inside a sync method which is called by this async method. All connected synchronous methods should be treated like async method only without "await". Because they are called from Task.Run of this method so they get converted to async method